# How to get focus of textarea in dotnetbrowser?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, web, dotnetbrowser

I am looking through the samples and I have got solution for focusing on dom element using tab.I am trying to focus on textarea which is on site,
so i had used virtual Tab key press to find that particular textarea and its working correctly.
But can anyone suggest how to directly focus on textarea. I also used excuteJavascript function but its not working.

Comment: You have some code?

Comment: Try calling the `focus` method on the element.

Comment: i had tried this ,ExecuteJavaScript("function(){$('#textareaid').focus();}")

Comment: asp.net web form or asp.net mvc view, which one?

Comment: add your code which you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

DotNetBrowser DOM API provides two methods: `DOMElement.Focus()` and `DOMElement.Blur()`. This functionality allows you to request focus on particular HTML DOM element.